# How to install ADT 11.0.0 on Eclipse(helios)

Tags: eclipse, adt

I am a **Fresh developer of Android application**, 
can anyone please help that how i can install ADT 11.0.0 on Eclipse(Helios),
i tried my best at least two days to overcome on this issue,but this error is coming continually that conflicting dependency is present.
**First Method:**
 I tried to put ADT 11.0.0 ***offline*** in eclipse but this is not affecting,means i just copy paste plugin and features folder of ADT 11.0.0 in eclipse(helios)..
**SECOND METHOD:**
I used this URL **http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/** to install ADT 11.0.0 ***online***,
Here is screen shots,

![This is an error which i am facing through online installation.]
**I shall be very thankful if anyone helps me**..........

Thanking you,
HelperANDFinder.

Comment: Maybe you could post the details of the error, or a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

@HelperAndFinder, you can directly download Eclipse ADT bundle, advantage is that:

With a single download, the Eclipse ADT bundle includes everything you need to begin developing apps:

```
Eclipse + ADT plugin
Android SDK Tools
Android Platform-tools
A version of the Android platform
A version of the Android system image for the emulator
```

Means you don't need to install ADT separately, just you need to download this bundle and your job done.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

> That is one way, other way is:
>
> Update an Eclipse IDE for Android development, in which you are more
> interested. Kindly look into this link to see step by step procedure:
>
> [Click here - This link provides step by step guidance on same.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidInstallation/article.html#updateeclipseide)

And for exploring Android in detail with to the point then [check out this link:](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html)

And to give you high level overview then

> Eclipse is IDE which supports Android App Development through plugin or as Complete package which is the first way.
>
> Androi SDK - A Software Development Kit that enables developers to create applications for the Android platform. The Android SDK includes sample projects with source code, development tools, an emulator, and required libraries to build Android applications. Applications are written using the Java programming language and run on Dalvik, a custom virtual machine designed for embedded use which runs on top of a Linuxkernel.
>
> ADT - ADT (Android Developer Tools) is a plugin for Eclipse that helps you to develop Android applications quickly. ADT provides GUI access to many of the command line SDK tools as well as a UI design tool for rapid prototyping, designing, and building of your application's user interface means just drag and drop thing is there to come up with basic layout for your application like we did in swing, and AWT kind of application. It's more than that just explore it more...;)

Comment: First a fall,thanks,as i told, am a fresh developer of android i used this method also so that i can learn speedly but using ADT bundle i can't understand the purpose of SDK manager, ADT, and eclipse in detail,i learn about these items through separate installation so kindly guide me i repeated my query how to add ADT 11.0.0 plugin in Eclipse(helios).  Thanking you, HelperAndFinder.

Comment: @HelperAndFinder, great to see your enthu to know internal mechanism, how stuffs work. In order to answer your query, you can see improved version of this question. All the best!

Comment: Boss again i am so much thankful to you that you provide help me consistently, but there is a problem, as i want to work on GingerBread(SDK 2.3.3) AP! 10,which is not working correctly with ADT 18.0 on new version of eclipse whereas i want to work on ADT 11.0,so if you give me that solution,this is a big help from your side. Thanks Vikas.